# Best way to customise wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Menu items description? Custom Walker for wp_nav_menu()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu)

I'm familiar with WordPress and using the WordPress menu system. But I'm looking for a way to add custom HTML to wp_nav_menu.

I'm trying to create a menu like this:
http://www.achievers.com/

Notice how the drop down menu under products contains a image and a link. I'd like to re-create this. I've looked at a few plugins, but would rather code it.

I don't mind hard coding the image and link, but I'd like to  keep the flexibility of using WordPress to manage the menus.

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading
Stephen Meehan

Comment: look in the related column to the right or search this site for "walker"

Answer (score 2):

Please check out this similar question with two directions you could use to solve your problem:

[Adding html elements to wp nav menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/adding-html-elements-to-wp-nav-menu/63912#63912)

I would try using either the wp_get_nav_menu_items() function or try using the 'wp_nav_menu_items' filter.

An easier solution (If you do not want to do much coding) would be to use The Uber Menu Plugin.  [wpmegamenu.com/](http://wpmegamenu.com/) I have used this on projects before and have been quite pleased.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, I'll take a look later today. I've spotted the megamenu plugin (might end up using it).